# How to add CA Certificate which contain invalid URI name " file://\\ " into keystore file

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, jboss5.x, keystore

I generated keystore file and  csr file using keytool, then I send that csr file to CA authority.
CA authority generated Certificate files both DER and  base64. When I put back those certificates into keystore I got such errors,

```
#2: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
Unparseable AuthorityInfoAccess extension due to
java.io.IOException: invalid URI name:file://\\

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
Unparseable CRLDistributionPoints extension due to
java.io.IOException: invalid URI name:file://\\
```

I found the solution on
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/meetingplace/7_1/english/troubleshooting/trbl_ssl_application_server.html
The Solution  is  `"Sign the certificate without the URL that includes the UNC path."`

But the CA, certificate cannot create without URL. 
Because of such restriction,
how to add CA Certificate which contain invalid URI name "file://\\" into keystore file?

Comment: There is no way to circumvent that exception except by passing it a valid URI. Is that a URI that you supply or does the CA add it for you?

Comment: Change CA? Why would you want a CA that uses a `file:///` URI for its CRL distribution point anyway? It can make sense to have CRLs in local files (perhaps pulled by a script or something), but they shouldn't impose *where* that file should be on your local system (which the `file:///` URI effectively does).

Comment: I found this blog. By following those procedures, certificate issue can be solved.[ca-ssl](http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2009/05/setting-up-company-ca-ssl-certificates.html)